# how to use protobuf-net in the xamarin ios pcl

Tags: ios, xamarin, protobuf-net

I am trying to use protobuf-net with the new xamarin ios pcl, and it's nuget packet doesn't appear to support the framework. Is there a way to import protobuf-net into the pcl?

Update:
I just found recompiling the PCL with the new Xamarin PCL definitions allowed the resulting library to be references. Nice work! Let me know when a new version is posted to Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet package includes PCL drops, but it is unclear to me what change you would have me make to the NuGet package here, as there is no specific "Xamarin" target that I know of; the [example targets are described here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package); protobuf-net currently includes a broad target of `portable-sl4+net40+wp7+windows8`. If you know of a target (or indeed a PCL build combination) that works for Xamarin for iOS, please let me know.

I should also note that the NuGet drop is the "Full" implementation, where meta-programming is performed at runtime. Because of the limitations in iOS, you may find you get better performance by using the "CoreOnly" implementation combined with the "precompile" tool, available from the google-code drop. [This is described here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html).

Comment: Hey Mark - Xamarin recently introduced full PCL profiles for IOS, I just recompiled with these see here http://blog.xamarin.com/pcl-projects-and-vs2013/

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell support for the portable target profile 259 [portable-win8+net45+wp8+wpa81] whould be nice - see [here] (http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY/preview)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use NuGet version of protobuf-net by manually editing the .csproj file for my portable library and setting the target framework profile to match protobuf-net:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile136</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

The resulting portable library worked well with Xamarin.Android. According to [this list](http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY/preview), it should work with Xamarin.iOS as well.